# Two ports having same PID

Tags: port, pid

I am very new to Java and may sound stupid in my question. I have Jboss on Port 8080 and also OracleXETNListener on Port 1521. When i check the command pronmpt i see both the ports are using the same Process ID which is 2908. Can this be a case? Also when i run my application on Jboss it gives error that port already in use.

```
Active Connections

  Proto  Local Address          Foreign Address        State           PID
  TCP    0.0.0.0:135            LR89PT1Y:0             LISTENING       1000
  TCP    0.0.0.0:371            LR89PT1Y:0             LISTENING       3916
  TCP    0.0.0.0:445            LR89PT1Y:0             LISTENING       4
  TCP    0.0.0.0:1521           LR89PT1Y:0             LISTENING       2908
  TCP    0.0.0.0:3389           LR89PT1Y:0             LISTENING       1544
  TCP    0.0.0.0:4445           LR89PT1Y:0             LISTENING       2112
  TCP    0.0.0.0:49152          LR89PT1Y:0             LISTENING       600
  TCP    0.0.0.0:49153          LR89PT1Y:0             LISTENING       564
  TCP    0.0.0.0:49154          LR89PT1Y:0             LISTENING       680
  TCP    0.0.0.0:49155          LR89PT1Y:0             LISTENING       984
  TCP    0.0.0.0:54570          LR89PT1Y:0             LISTENING       2872
  TCP    0.0.0.0:54587          LR89PT1Y:0             LISTENING       672
  TCP    0.0.0.0:57065          LR89PT1Y:0             LISTENING       3040
  TCP    10.119.52.86:1521      LPDMW01HN4D3BS:54571   ESTABLISHED     2908
  TCP    10.119.52.86:54571     LPDMW01HN4D3BS:1521    ESTABLISHED     2872
  TCP    10.119.52.86:57493     sindprmpsp04:microsoft-ds  ESTABLISHED     4
  TCP    10.119.52.86:64337     d050876bc02:http       CLOSE_WAIT      1444
  TCP    10.119.64.250:139      LR89PT1Y:0             LISTENING       4
  TCP    10.119.64.250:56423    SPTCDI002:59530        ESTABLISHED     7328
  TCP    10.119.64.250:56425    SPTCDI002:59535        ESTABLISHED     7328
  TCP    10.119.64.250:56426    169.77.61.253:5061     ESTABLISHED     4872
  TCP    10.119.64.250:56427    SPTCDI002:59530        ESTABLISHED     7328
  TCP    10.119.64.250:56448    SINDWINP40:microsoft-ds  ESTABLISHED     4
  TCP    10.119.64.250:56460    inprlcfl11:microsoft-ds  ESTABLISHED     4
  TCP    10.119.64.250:56489    inprbcfl01:microsoft-ds  ESTABLISHED     4
  TCP    10.119.64.250:56550    itrhkdcep2:8000        ESTABLISHED     2068
  TCP    10.119.64.250:56663    vsipe0vl134:http       CLOSE_WAIT      4776
  TCP    10.119.64.250:56664    vsipe0vl134:http       CLOSE_WAIT      4776
  TCP    10.119.64.250:56665    vsipe0vl134:http       CLOSE_WAIT      4776
  TCP    10.119.64.250:56696    LR89PT1Y:56697         ESTABLISHED     2872
  TCP    10.119.64.250:56697    LR89PT1Y:56696         ESTABLISHED     2908
  TCP    10.119.64.250:56934    sdecdc1na06:microsoft-ds  ESTABLISHED     4
  TCP    10.119.64.250:56940    gsc-prod:44527         ESTABLISHED     4676
  TCP    10.119.64.250:57018    SINDWINP37:microsoft-ds  ESTABLISHED     4
  TCP    10.119.64.250:57035    169.77.211.185:8443    ESTABLISHED     7220
  TCP    10.119.64.250:57038    169.77.211.185:8443    ESTABLISHED     7220
  TCP    10.119.64.250:57046    169.77.235.249:8443    TIME_WAIT       0
  TCP    10.119.64.250:57047    169.77.235.249:8443    TIME_WAIT       0
  TCP    10.119.64.250:57051    169.77.235.249:8443    TIME_WAIT       0
  TCP    10.119.64.250:57057    169.77.235.249:8443    ESTABLISHED     9832
  TCP    10.119.64.250:57058    169.77.235.249:8443    ESTABLISHED     9832
  TCP    10.119.64.250:57060    169.77.235.249:8443    ESTABLISHED     9832
  TCP    10.119.64.250:57061    169.77.235.249:8443    ESTABLISHED     7536
  TCP    10.119.64.250:57063    proxybc270park:http    TIME_WAIT       0
  TCP    10.119.64.250:57064    LR89PT1Y:57050         TIME_WAIT       0
  TCP    10.119.64.250:59542    SPTCMX005:55813        ESTABLISHED     7328
  TCP    10.119.64.250:59544    SPTCDI001:59530        ESTABLISHED     4872
  TCP    10.119.64.250:63268    SPTCDI002:59535        ESTABLISHED     4872
  TCP    127.0.0.1:5152         LR89PT1Y:0             LISTENING       2440
  TCP    127.0.0.1:8080         LR89PT1Y:0             LISTENING       2908
  TCP    127.0.0.1:54568        LR89PT1Y:0             LISTENING       2908
  TCP    127.0.0.1:62522        LR89PT1Y:0             LISTENING       1508
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems OracleXETNSListener also use port 8080, so process id is for the listener.  When JBoss try to start it can't bind to the 8080 port.

To change the OracleXETNSListenr port follow these instructions: http://hodentekhelp.blogspot.be/2008/08/my-oracle-10g-xe-is-on-port-8080-can-i.html